# Are there any implementations of STL that are not messy and can actually be read?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a readable implementation of the STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127612/is-there-a-readable-implementation-of-the-stl)

I've been trying to grok the source of the STL and frankly after looking at multiple implementations, I'm left shaking my head. The sheer verbosity of the code is breathtaking. No, not the complexity of the concepts, I mean the way it was implemented, the layers of macros that I suppose are there to deal with platform issues, and the spacing, line breaks, and just total lack of comments. Are there any good implementations that are readable?

Comment: Ugh...  I know what you're talking about.  I would just try not to look at it.

Comment: Seems this question was answered already, so I vote to close it :)

Comment: you should include a link to the answered question. :)

Comment: Macros for potability? The only popular portable STL I know of is STLPort. Look at the implementation that came with your compiler; it shouldn't have that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several implantations of the stl but the STL is very generic and is used by thousands of client programs.  Small programs written to solve small problems are often succinct and easy to read any sufficient generic code that runs in the real world is not trivial to read.